# SQL Case Condition on joined table

Tags: sql

I need to  modify this sql using a case condition, i need all of model to echo but only echo tw if the where condition meets. What would be the best way to do this?

```
SELECT * FROM model
LEFT OUTER JOIN tw
ON model.model_name=tw.model
WHERE tw.completed = 1 AND tw.stock = 0
ORDER BY model.id
```

Comment: The result of any query is a single table a unique structure. As such, you cannot have holes when conditions are not met. What you can have is NULLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT m.*, t2.*
FROM model m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     tw
     ON m.model_name = tw.model AND
        tw.completed = 1 AND tw.stock = 0
ORDER BY m.id;
```